# How to check ANT+ capability?

Tags: windows-8.1

How can I find out whether my laptop has ANT+ capabilities? (I mean by using the operation system, not by checking the laptop specs.)

Comment: I don't think any laptops have ANT+ buit in ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Hmm that would explain why I haven't found anything about this... There are ANT+ USB sticks, maybe that's all we got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I find out whether my laptop has ANT+ capabilities?

> Many Android phones, tablets and other mobile devices have built-in ANT+ support – i.e. native ANT+ support. See the [ANT+ Product Directory](http://www.thisisant.com/directory) for a current list.

Source [Consumer FAQ](http://www.thisisant.com/consumer/ant-101/consumer-faq/category/244/)

---

#### What if my device does not have ANT+ capabilities?

> If your device is not listed on the [ANT+ Product Directory](http://www.thisisant.com/directory), you
> can enable ANT+ communication with an accessory/adapter through your
> device’s USB port.  Several Android accessory options are available:
>
> - [ANT USB Stick](http://www.thisisant.com/directory/usb-ant-stick)
> - [Selfloops ANT+ Accessory](http://www.selfloops.com/products/accessories.html)
> - [Tacx T2090 ANT+ Dongle micro USB](http://www.thisisant.com/directory/ant-dongle-micro-usb-t2090)

Source [ANT+ in Phones and Tablets](http://www.thisisant.com/consumer/ant-101/ant-in-phones/)

---